# UIKeyboard while hiding/showing methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uikeyboard

Is there any code/method to catch when the keyboard is animated half way to show/hide completely? I need to perform some action when keyboard is half visible just before keyboardDidShow notification is called.
Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in method for this. However, as @Aaron Brager pointed out, you can get the duration of the keyboard's presentation animation using `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` from the user info of the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification. Then all you have to do is divide that value by 2 and delay the execution your action by that amount. Here's an example:

```
- (void)keyBoardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSTimeInterval duration = [self keyboardAnimationDurationForNotification:notification];

    double delayInSeconds = duration / 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    });
}

- (NSTimeInterval)keyboardAnimationDurationForNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue *value = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval duration = 0;
    [value getValue:&duration];
    return duration;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyBoardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: I think you could just halve the animation duration from the UIKeyboardWillShowNotification's userinfo dictionary, right?

Comment: It helped. Thanks 0x7fffffff and Aaron.